# Filtering a nested array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my app I have a structure like this:

```
[ ["section title", [{ item }, { item } ... ]],
  ["section title", [{ item }, { item } ... ]], ... and so on
```

In my view, I place the sections in panels, and their internal lists in lists:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="section in index">
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>{{section[0]}}</strong></div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in section[1]">
        ... item view here
```

But now I want to add search, and I want the search results to contain only items from the internal arrays.  I can put a filter function on the top level...

```
ng-repeat="section in index | filter:matching()"
```

and have the `matching()` function produce a flat list of items within the sections that match the search,but the html is setup to handle a sectional structure, not a flat list.  What should I do?

1. have my filter produce results in the sectional structure, sometimes with empty sections (where no items match), and then hide the empty sections?
2. fix it somehow in the html, something like this...

   ```
   <div ng-if="searchText">
       --- I don't know what goes here
   </div>
   <div ng-if="!searchText">
       --- same as above
   ```

   This 2nd idea seems terrible to me.
3. Something cleverer (hopefully) that I'm missing

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Theoratically, the following code should work for you (it worked for me)

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="section in index | filter:matching()">
  <div class="panel-heading" ng-if="!searchText"><strong>{{section[0]}}</strong></div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in section[1]">
        ... item view here
```

Though this will create multiple div and ul tags, but you can always use this

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat-start="section in index | filter:matching()" style="display:none"></li>
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in section">
        ... item view here
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat-end style="display:none"></li>
</ul>
```